# Why is "${1-"$var"}" (option 6 down below) not mentioned in POSIX?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, ksh, dash

The only reference I could find [in the spec is this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_02_03):

> It would be desirable to include the statement "The characters from an enclosed "${" to the matching '}' shall not be affected by the double-quotes", similar to the one for "$()". However, historical practice in the System V shell prevents this.

The obvious question is: "what is that historical issue" and, more importantly, how does it affect us today ?

At the `C.2.5 Parameters and Variables` heading further down on that page there are a lot of examples of quoted expansions in what seems an exhaustive effort to list all of them, however, nowhere a twice double quoted example appear.

### Description

The issue is related to the outputs of this 6 alternatives of quoting:

- `$b`, `"$b"`, `${a-$b}`, `${a-"$b"}` `"${a-$b}"` and `"${a-"$b"}"`

The first five are defined by POSIX and some shells agree on the result of such expansions. Note that some values get split on the value of `$IFS`:

```bash
$ export a=abc; for sh in dash ksh93 bash; do $sh -c 'IFS="bl"; b=value 
  printf "<%s> " 1$b 2"$b" 3${a-$b} 4${a-"$b"} 5"${a-$b}" 6"${a-"$b"}";
  echo'; done

<1va> <ue> <2value> <3a> <c> <4a> <c> <5abc> <6abc> 
<1va> <ue> <2value> <3a> <c> <4a> <c> <5abc> <6abc> 
<1va> <ue> <2value> <3a> <c> <4a> <c> <5abc> <6abc>
```

However, is `"${1-"$var"}"` defined somewhere in the spec ?

That is: with **repeated** double quotes, external and internal.

### Additional 1

Just as related information, look at this results: Note that the only difference of the previous code to this next code is that `$a` is unset:

```bash
$ unset a; for sh in dash ksh93 bash; do $sh -c 'IFS="bl"; b=value 
  printf "<%s> " 1$b 2"$b" 3${a-$b} 4${a-"$b"} 5"${a-$b}" 6"${a-"$b"}";
  echo'; done

<1va> <ue> <2value> <3va> <ue> <4value> <5value> <6value> 
<1va> <ue> <2value> <3va> <ue> <4value> <5value> <6va> <ue> 
<1va> <ue> <2value> <3va> <ue> <4value> <5value> <6value>
```

### Additional 2

Common shells act in conflicting ways when actually testing all quoting options.

```bash
$ for sh in dash ksh93 bash; do $sh -c 'IFS="bl"; b=value 
  printf "<%s> " 1\n 2"\n" 3${a-\n} 4${a-"\n"} 5"${a-\n}" 6"${a-"\n"}";
  echo'; done

<1n> <2\n> <3n> <4\n> <5\n> <6\n> 
<1n> <2\n> <3n> <4\n> <5\n> <6n> 
<1n> <2\n> <3n> <4\n> <5\n> <6n>
```

And that is without including zsh!.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140700/discussion-on-question-by-quartzcristal-why-is-1-var-option-6-down-belo).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `"${1-"$var"}"` not mentioned in POSIX?

It looks like it's not at all clear what it should mean to have quotes both inside and outside the expansion,
and there appears to be an approved change to leave it undefined.

But, having quotes outside the expansion is normal, it's what we do to prevent word (field) splitting and globbing. Having them inside the expansion is also mentioned:

Section [2.2.3 Double-Quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) says

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( `""` ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters backquote, <dollar-sign>, and <backslash>, as follows:
>
> [...]
> Within the string of characters from an enclosed `${` to the matching `}`, *an even number of unescaped double-quotes* or single-quotes, if any, shall occur.

and for command substitutions, it says:

> The input characters within the quoted string that are also enclosed between `$(` and the matching `)` shall not be affected by the double-quotes [...]

That's not mentioned for parameter expansion, so the implication must be that the characters inside `${...}` are also affected by the quotes outside.

The example of `${foo-\n}` vs. `"${foo-\n}"` (your cases 3 and 5) show that in effect, with the outer quotes protecting the backslash, just as in `\n` vs. `"\n"`.

---

But it doesn't seem to mention both inside and outside quotes together, and it's not that clear what that should do anyway.

If the characters inside are affected by the outer quotes, then
one possible interpretation would be that the first inside double quote *ends* quoting, the second restarts it and `whatever` is then unquoted.
Ksh seems to follow this interpretation rather consistently, e.g.:

```
$ printf "<%s>\n" "${foo-"foo \n *"}"
<foo>
<n>
<file1.txt>
<file2.txt>
```

I'm not sure that's very useful, and pretty much no other shell does that. (At least from the relatively recent ones I tried.)

With the others, many output just `<foo \n *>`, as if the string was quoted in full, as if the inner double-quotes just, well, emphasize the fact the characters are supposed to be quoted.

And then Bash and Dash seem to treat the backslash in an inconsistent way, and print `<foo n *>` which doesn't appear to match any logical rule I can think of as the `\n` acts as if it were not quoted, while the `*` and the spaces act as if they are.

It gets even hairier if you add *single* quotes.

---

Witnessing that inconsistency, it's perhaps not surprising that the matter has been discussed before, and [there appears to be a change pending that would explicitly leave that undefined](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=221), the relevant part being:

> For parameter expansions other than the four varieties that provide
> for substring processing, within the string of characters from an
> enclosed "${" to the matching '}', the double-quotes within which
> the expansion occurs shall preserve the literal value of all
> characters, with the exception of the characters double-quote,
> backquote, , and . If any unescaped
> double-quote characters occur within the string, other than in
> embedded command substitutions, the behavior is unspecified.

and

> Shell implementations differ widely in their handling of unescaped
> double-quote characters inside "${...}" (except for the four
> substring-processing variants). Hence this standard leaves the
> behavior unspecified.
> [...]
> Differences in processing the "${...}" form led to inconsistencies
> between the historical System V shell, BSD, and KornShells, and
> the text in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2008 is an
> attempt to converge them without breaking too many applications.

That would appear to be those historical reasons.

The way that first one reads, it seems it means `${foo-"bar"}` also, and not just `"${foo-"bar"}"`, even though
the former doesn't seem all that prone to giving different results between the shells.

I didn't find the 2010 discussions on that, but here's a few messages from 2016, these also touch
on how single quotes would work:

[Robert Elz](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg00181.html):

> Quoted ${ } is one of the [hairiest] parts of the shell, and scariest in a
> sense, and is really difficult to duplicate - and it is not at all surprising
> that all this is left as unspecified, or will be, in issue 8 (and for now
> it is simply incomprehensible).

[Chet Ramey](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg00174.html):

> OK.  Geoff's position is that the issue 7 text is a requirement on the
> application, not the shell, in addition to the wording being ambiguous
> about the intent that the requirement applies separately to single
> and double quotes (i.e., you can't nest them).
>
> As such, there wasn't any shell behavior to point to as correct when
> interpretation 221 was being discussed, and part of the discussion
> involved deciding what was correct and expressing it clearly.